# reporting services - determining report GUID from old report name

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reportserver

I'm trying to use a combination of the SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services ReportServer database and the [report server web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155071%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) to determine the GUID for a particular report.  What I want is to see a list of the previous names of a report that has been renamed or moved on the report server.  I know a report's history snapshots stays with it when you rename it because the report has a unique GUID that doesn't change when you rename it.  However, I can't seem to find a place in the database where previous names of a report are associated with the report's GUID.  I can't find any instance of an old report name in the database, so I don't know if this is even stored.  When I look at all the values of `Catalog.Path` and `Catalog.Name` in the database, the old values are not included from before the report rename.  Is it possible, given a value like MyAwesomeReport, to associate that with a GUID like 7af3fe6d-b4ea-4cd8-8430-280392cba428, so that I can determine that this report has actually been renamed to MySuperAwesomeReport?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you to be able to determine a history for these is to build your own ETL script which would look up the current name of the reports, stored by GUID, and hold this in another structure.  Having looked through the ReportServer database, I don't believe the name attribute of a report is held historically.  I would based my implementation for this off the Sample Code for Reporting Utilization Stat's which is available in the examples on codeplex.  I'll see if I can find the link to that example, its how I learned the most about how the ReportServer database is used and structured.